# Combining Solr score with externalField value

Tags: solr

I have a list of book ratings stored in an external file. Ratings are stored in `book_id=rating` format and I can successfully query this information with Solr queries.

If I want to filter the search by specific keywords and have rating applied only to the matching documents it works well:

```
..?q=my_book_title+AND+{!func}book_rating
```

My problem is that field boosting doesn't seem to work in combination with external rating.

Let's say if I want to boost the book title like this:

```
..?q=my-book-title+AND+{!func}book_rating&qf=title^100.0,content^50.0,field(books_rating)^2
```

It always seems to score documents only based on the `externalField` rating.
How can I make Solr include boosting and combine its score with the external rating?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use &bf paramater. 
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bf_.28Boost_Functions.29